# How do I get the values in my servlet from my JSP type radio inputs with the values yes or no?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, input, file-writing

I am new to JSP and servlets. 
**I want to write the user's information to a file if the user checks the yes checkbox**, my code is giving me an exception on my if statement checking if the checkbox was checked.

Here is my jsp :

```
<p>Would you like us to save your personal information? 
    <form  action="inputservlet" method="post">
        <label>yes</label>
        <input type="radio" name="personalInfo" value="yes">
        <label>no</label>
        <input type="radio" name="personalInfo" value="no"><br>
        <label>Email: </label>
        <input type="email" name="email" value="${user1.email}"><br>
        <label>First Name: </label>
        <input type="text" name="firstName" value="${user1.firstName}"><br>
         <label>Last Name: </label>
        <input type="text" name="lastName" value="${user1.lastName}"><br>

    </form>
```

Here is my servlet doPost method:

```
@Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        // get parameters from the request (if box was checked) 

        String infoCheckbox = request.getParameter("personalInfo");

        String plan = request.getParameter("plan");
        String email = request.getParameter("email");
        String firstName = request.getParameter("firstName");
        String lastName = request.getParameter("lastName");


        //get file to write personal info to from web.xml
        ServletContext context = getServletContext();
        String fileName = context.getInitParameter("filename");   

// Save  personal information to user object
         User user1 = new User(firstName, lastName, email);
         request.setAttribute("user1", user1); 
         UserFile userfile1= new UserFile();

// If checkbox was checked, write user to file. 

        if(infoCheckbox.equalsIgnoreCase("yes")){
            userfile1.addRecord(user1, fileName);

        }
```

I am getting a null pointer exception at this line:

```
if(infoCheckbox.equalsIgnoreCase("yes")){
            userfile1.addRecord(user1, fileName);

        }
```

I checked yes when I tested it. 
Shouldn't infoCheckbox be equal to either 'yes' or 'no' depending on the box that was checked? 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: try checking if your **infoCheckbox** value is null or not ,then try to compare .

Comment: it is null, but it shouldn't be as I checked yes. So the value should be "yes"